# Why does "desktop window manager" have very high CPU useage?

Tags: windows, windows-10, cpu, cpu-usage

I am suffering a very high CPU utilization on desktop window manager process - up to 90-95 percent.

Apart of it, no other process consumes more than 5%.

How can I solve it?

My main computer details:

Windows 10 Pro, Intel i7-5500U CPU 2.4G, Installed RAM 8G, 64Bit

Comment: Have you updated Windows and your graphic drivers to the latest version ?

Comment: install the WPT (part of the Win10 SDK: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk), run **WPRUI.exe**, select first level and under resource **CPU usage**. Now click on start, capture 1 minute of the CPU usage. Now compress the larger ETL file as 7z/RAR, upload it to OneDrive, create a share link and post the link here. I'll see analyze it and look why DWM causes such a high CPU usage

Comment: @magicandre1981 I hope the link is ok: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=E102BB67D916556D%212896    . Thank you!

Comment: ok, I got the file and posted the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I checked the [ETL file with WPA](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-42-WPT-CPU-Analysis) and saw that indeed the Intel GPU driver `igd10iumd64.dll` causes the CPU usage by calling the functions `ntdll.dll!RtlLeaveCriticalSection` and `ntdll.dll!RtlEnterCriticalSection` very often.

[image]

Your Intel driver has version `10.18.15.4256`, which is a bit older. Try the newer driver [4300](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/25484/Intel-Graphics-Driver-for-Windows-7-8-1-10-15-40-) or the latest Beta driver [4380](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/25749/Intel-Beta-Graphics-Driver-for-Windows-7-8-1-10-15-40-).

Comment: I updated to 4300. I will update if I will see the problem again. Thank you!

Comment: Meanwhile CPU is about 5% !!!

Comment: In my case it was my Nvidia drivers that needed to be updated. Thanks for the help.